# Question about BB/100

Tags: cash-game, software

I'm using the [fpdb](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fpdb/index.php?title=Main_Page) tracker and want to know my **BB/100**.
The program itself doesn't give such information, instead it gives me a graph of my hands and the total BB i won (i suppose they're `Big Blinds`, dunno if they're `Big Bets`, don't know the difference; suppose they're the same).

Here it is in real numbers:

- *Sample size:*  `1802 hands`
- *BB:*           `85.13`
- *BB/100:*       `?`

**It's correct if i just do:**

- *100s in sample size:* `1802 / 100` = **18.02** (how many 100s in my samplesize)
- *BB/100:* `85.13 / 18.02` = **4.72** (BB in 100 hands)

**EDIT**

Just checked the relation between $$ and BB won today and it seems that **BB** is doubled.
Today i won *$0.78* (211 hands) but my *BB* is *19.5* just for today (i play **0.01 / 0.02**), so `0.02 * 19.5 = $0.39` and not **$0.78**.
Why it is halved and how can i compute my `BB/100` the correct way?
tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what game you're playing. Anyway, as far as I've always seen, bb means big blinds and BB means big *bets*. In most poker variants, the betting size doubles at some point in the hand. For example, in limit hold'em, on the turn and river, the bet size is doubled. The size of the bet on the turn and river *is* the big bet size.

You must be playing NLHE, because most NLHE players quote their game in terms of blind size (e.g., if you say I'm playing 0.01 / 0.02, you probably mean that's the size of the small and big blinds, respectively). In LHE games, 0.01 / 0.02 would mean the big blind is 0.01 and the *big bet* is 0.02. Most NLHE players quote their win rate in terms of bb/100 (**NOT** BB/100). So, your win rate is 4.72 / 2 = 2.36bb/100 hands.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry didn't mentioned my game. I'm playing 6-max NLHE cash game and blinds are _$0.01-$0.02_ (microstakes). The program indeed gives me **BB** (they're typed as that), thus it's strongly **NL** (i didn't found any limit reference to it, only what NL stakes to select, that's why i got confused). So in this case it's safe to just halve my BB/100 and be done? thanx

Comment: Yes, just halve your BB/100 and you will get the number that NL players report as their win rate. BB/100 = 2*bb/100. NL players report bb/100 as their win rate.